# Older isotope portfolio rows shifting downward by 1 pixel on hover

Tags: css, javascript

https://visaud.io/shows/

Please see the above link. As you'll see, if you hover over the portfolio items, they either shift to the next column/line (in the case of columns 1-3) or shift all the content below it in the case of the 4th column.

I don't recall when the issue started happening, though perhaps it's the result of a WordPress core update? Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated. I'm hoping it's just a simple CSS oversight that I might have missed or accidentally messed up.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the border at the bottom of `#portfolio-items article` when you hover.

There actually doesn't appear to be a border at the bottom of the `article` element, the gray border you see is at the bottom of the the link using`#portfolio-items article .project-meta` at the bottom of the portfolio item.

So you have two options, re-write the CSS section for hover to change the gray to green, by adding a rule like this:

```
#portfolio-items article:hover .project-meta {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #33be25;
}
```

And then remove the border from this rule:

```
#main-nav a:hover,
#main-nav .hover>a,
#main-nav .current_page_item>a,
#main-nav .current_page_parent>a,
#main-nav .current-menu-item>a,
.projects-carousel a:hover,
#portfolio-items>article:hover,
.team-member:hover {
         border-bottom: 1px solid #33be25;
}
```

But that will effect all the other items so maybe just add this rule:

```
#portfolio-items>article:hover {
     border-bottom:none;
}
```

I think what would be more effective though would just be to update this rule:

```
#portfolio-items article {
     margin-bottom: 50px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; /* add this line */
}
```

So what you're basically doing is including the logo already, so that when the items load they have their set size... ...then when you hover all you're doing is changing the colour from transparent to green.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This is unrelated to the issue I mentioned, but the isotope portfolio filter interface is also broken for some reason, and I don't know enough about JavaScript to fix it. Is that something you could take a look at as well? Thank you again!

Comment: Looked at the isotope.js instantiation in the JS & it appears as though everything is in order - but when you now click on it it loads a new page.  The script has `e.preventDefault();` so the fact that it loads a new page tells me that it's not executing the isotope code.  I enabled preserve log so I could see what triggers in there AFTER the filter links are clicked.  `undefined is not a function (near '...$('.single-image, .image-gallery, .gallery-item a').fancybox...')` is shown twice.  Since that line loads BEFORE your isotope the code after it isn't executing either.

Comment: The problem isn't with isotope but rather with the fancy box scripting.  You'll have to address that as it appears to be in the FancyBox error displays.

Comment: If my answer above fixed the issue you were having you should accept it as the answer and start a new question to fix your FancyBox/Isotope scripting issue.  But since it's basically a javascript issue it should also probably move over to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I wasn't using fancybox for anything anymore, so I removed that and fixed everything. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to help.  Is everything resolved?

Comment: Yes, thank you! You can go to the original page and see it working as expected.